# How to make ASP.Net WebAPI Server available on LAN

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, iis-10

I'm trying to Host **ASP.NET WebAPI** and make that available for all devices connected on the LAN.

I can able to access the API from my localhost

[Getting Proper Response from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whmx8.png)

When i try to access the API from Other computer in the same LAN, API is getting into Bad Request - Invalid Hostname HTTP Error 400

[Bad Request - Invalid Hostname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWr1H.png)

I have also added the **Inbound Rules** for port number 52022

My binding configuration in

> C:\Users***\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

```
       <sites>
            <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
                <application path="/">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52022:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52022:" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
            <siteDefaults>
                <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
                <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
            </siteDefaults>
            <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
            <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
        </sites>
```

Still I could not be able to access API from another Computer which are connected in the same LAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make Web application available on Lan Simply You need to deploy your service on local host.
Here are some links

[Deploy web api on localhost](http://dotnetmentors.com/web-api/host-asp-net-web-api-in-iis-using-visual-studio-publish.aspx)

and

[Deploy asp.net web api on localhost](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/publish-and-host-Asp-Net-web-api/)

Comment: I have published my webapi project as file type like you mentioned but still I couldn't able to access my API

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byrmhv4D-ohEc1VTd1dIVHVDdlE  See the error screenshot

Comment: Please check out your web config file

Comment: What kind of configurations should be checked in web config file.

Comment: Please check for the connection string and permissions.

Comment: ok, thank you. I have check connection string that is fine. What kind of permission should I give.

Comment: I have reconfigured my web configuration file.